# How do I pre-calculate cell heights on a background thread to improve table view performance?

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, uitableview, cocoa-touch

I've heard of this tactic to improve cell loading performance quite a few times, and it's mentioned as a technique in [this blog post by Jared Sinclair](http://blog.jaredsinclair.com/post/81410534498/cell-height-caching-dilemmas-in-unread), but how would I go about doing this?

To my knowledge the table view (if you don't supply an estimated row height) asks for the height of every cell in the table view as soon as it has a data source. Therefore, at what point would I be able to do "pre-calculations"? In my head that would mean supplying a handful at the beginning to allow the table view to have a foundation, then calculate the rest on a background thread. But this doesn't seem possible, as the table view asks for *all* the cell heights.

In Jared Sinclair's post he also mentions that he does this *instead* of estimated row height, so I don't think that would have anything to do with the solution.

So how do I leverage background threads to improve cell height loading? From what I can tell my app has a several second delay when about to display around 100 variable-height cells, and I'd like to improve this.

Answer (score -1):

Although not exactly what you are asking, but have you looked at asyncdisplaykit?

Checkout http://asyncdisplaykit.org

UIKit is all about main thread, so calculating heights on the BG thread would be hard. Rather than doing that why not look at something that was meant to be used on the BG thread.

In one of my project I was able to use ASCollectionView (async counterpart of UICollectionView) to boost the loading/scrolling performance. May be ASCollectionView would do that job for you too.

Comment: Could you please explain how doing cell height calculations in the background would be "hard?" I have done this very easily using good ole GCD with no issues whatsoever.

Comment: you havent provide enough details to the question?